# Import Error : No module named django_orm

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-1.9

While importing `CredentialsField` from *oauth2client.django_orm*, I am getting:

```
Import Error: No module named django_orm
```

I've already installed the prerequisites: *django-orm* and *python-oauth2*.

Comment: You need to put trace / actual - error  that you are getting within your post

Comment: You need to add django_orm in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there's been a change on the OAuth2 library:

> Refactor all django-related code into
>   oauth2client.contrib.django_util. Add DjangoORMStorage, remove
>   FlowField. (#546)

You can check this [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Perhaps you can try something like this (I don't get any import errors when running it, but I am not sure it works):

```
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.storage import DjangoORMStorage
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.models import CredentialsField
```

Comment: Just an update, I have tried it now and it seems to be working fine. I can save the credentials on the CredentialsField and retrieve it using DjangoORMStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on [Drive API Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django) isn't upto date (Last updated in May 2015).

Use these imports instead:

```
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import CredentialsField
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import FlowField
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import Storage
```

If you're following API Guide, then more imports will break. Developers of oauth2client have moved all non-core modules (django_orm, xsrfutil, appengine, etc.) to [contrib](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/9da04e00a9e69a07fe2df6d4d7a8974c5ee09c25). Refer to [oauth2client source code](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) if you get more `ImportError`s.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the oauth2client library has since been deprecated. Check out the more up to date `google-auth` library https://google-auth.readthedocs.io

To create a credentials object with an auth token: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#user-credentials

```python
import google.oauth2.credentials

credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    'access_token')
```