# Integrating Google Sign-in and Calendar access in an Django application

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign-in and access to Google Calendar, in a Django app. I've successfully dealt with the former using  `python-social-auth`.

I've also managed to get a simple django app with calendar access using `google-api-python-client` based on the code [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/django_sample).

But I'm confused as to how I should integrate them in a single workflow where I can get calendar access permission during user sign-in instead. I'd appreciate if you could provide me with some example code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I managed to get it working:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import CredentialsField

class Credentials(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    credential = CredentialsField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'credentials'
```

settings.py

```
.
.
.
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = ''  
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ''
GOOGLE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://<domain>/oauth2/redirect/'
.
.
.
```

views.py

```
import httplib2
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest,
                         HttpResponseRedirect)
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from oauth2client.contrib import xsrfutil
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import Storage

from .models import Credentials


def get_flow(request):    
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope=settings.GOOGLE_SCOPE,
        redirect_uri=settings.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
        access_type='offline',
        state=''
    )
    return flow


def login(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', 'home')
    request.session['next'] = next

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        flow = get_flow(request)
        flow.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                       request.user)
        request.session['flow'] = pickle.dumps(flow).decode('iso-8859-1')
        redirect_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return redirect(redirect_uri)
    else:
        return redirect(reverse_lazy(next))


def oauth2redirect(request):
    # Make sure that the request is from who we think it is
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                   request.GET.get('state').encode('utf8'),
                                   request.user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    code = request.GET.get('code')
    error = request.GET.get('error')

    if code:
        flow = get_flow(request)
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

        request.session['creds'] = credentials.to_json()
        email = credentials.id_token.get("email")
        user_exists = False
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            user_exists = True
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = create_user(credentials)

        # Since we've oauth2'd the user, we should set the backend appropriately
        # This is usually done by the authenticate() method.
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        # Refresh token is needed for renewing google api access token
        if credentials.refresh_token:
            user.refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token
        user.save()

        storage = Storage(Credentials, 'id', user, 'credential')
        storage.put(credentials)

        # Register that the user has successfully logged in
        auth_login(request, user)

        next = request.session.get('next', reverse_lazy('/'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    elif code is None and error:
        return HttpResponse(str(error))
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()


@login_required
def logout(request):
    user = request.user
    credentials = Credentials.objects.get(id=user.id)
    credentials.revoke(httplib2.Http())
    credentials.delete()
    storage = Storage(Credentials, 'id', user, 'credential')
    storage.delete()

    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: did you replace python-social-auth with your code or use the two together?

Comment: I did not use python-social-auth.

Comment: I cannot even get it to run.  I'm getting `ImportError: No module named django_orm` when I try `manage.py migrate`

Comment: I don't seem to have that problem. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/40174968/959654 might help?

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Calendar Quickstart for Python](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python). It includes signing-in and using that authentication to generate tokens. This tokens will be used to perform Calendar API calls. Play with it and add your own code.

Here's a snippet:

```
def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
if flags:
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials
```